# Webkit Scroll Bar - Hide Scroll Bar Y of parent element but leave visible on child

Tags: html, css, scroll, webkit, scrollbar

I have an outer element with `max-height` and `overflow-y:scroll`. I don't want to have the scrollbar visible on the .parent-element therefore I am using `::-webkit-scrollbar`. However in the `.parent-element` I have a child with max-height and `overflow-y: scroll` too which I would like to have the scrollbar visible, when try apply `display: block` on `::-webkit-scrollbar` of the child element it is being ignored and overridden by the parent's, ending up with the scrollbar not visible on both.

Is there a way on webkit to have the scroll bar visible on the child but hidden on the parent?

Below is the sample html and css. Please note that this is not the actual html and css being used, I am just making use of basic html and css to explain the issue.

HTML

```
<div class="parent-element">
    <div class="div-one">
       <p>Multi Line text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="div-two">
       <p>Multi Line text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="div-three">
      <ul class="scrollable-list">
          <li>List Item 1</li>
          <li>List Item 2</li>
          <li>List Item 3</li>
          ...(500 more)
      </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.parent-element{
    width: 100%;
    padding: 20px;
    max-height: 700px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
.parent-element ::-webkit-scrollbar {
   display: none;
}
.div-one, .div-two, .div-three{
   width:100%;
    display: block;
}
.div-three .scrollable-list{
    width: 100%;
    max-height: 300px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
.parent-element .div-three ::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't give parent max-height.

```css
.parent-element{
    width: 100%;
    height: 130px;
    overflow-y: hidden;
}
.div-three{
    height: 100%;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent-element">
    <div class="div-one">
    </div>
    <div class="div-two">
    </div>
    <div class="div-three">
      <ul class="scrollable-list">
          <li>List Item 1</li>
          <li>List Item 2</li>
          <li>List Item 3</li>
          <li>List Item 4</li>
          <li>List Item 5</li>
          <li>List Item 6</li>
          ...(500 more)
      </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `overflow-y: no-scroll;` on the parent, `overflow-y: scroll;` on the child, and get rid of the `display: none` and the `display: block`

HTML:

```
<div class="parent-element">
<div class="div-one">
   <p>Multi Line text</p>
</div>
<div class="div-two">
   <p>Multi Line text</p>
</div>
<div class="div-three">
  <ul class="scrollable-list">
      <li>List Item 1</li>
      <li>List Item 2</li>
      <li>List Item 3</li>
      <li>List Item 4</li>
      <li>List Item 5</li>
      <li>List Item 6</li>
      <li>List Item 7</li>
      <li>List Item 8</li>
      <li>List Item 9</li>
      ...(500 more)
  </ul>
</div>
```

And CSS:

```
.parent-element{
    width: 100%;
    padding: 20px;
    max-height: 400px;
    overflow-y: no-scroll;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.parent-element ::-webkit-scrollbar {
}
.div-one, .div-two, .div-three{
   width:100%;
    display: block;
}
.div-three .scrollable-list{
    width: 100%;
    max-height: 200px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

as you did not set the width of the div-three what you thought to be the scroll-bar of the parent actually was the scroll bar of the child that expanded to the right

```css
.parent-element{
    width: 100%;
    max-height: 700px;
    
}

.div-three .scrollable-list{
width:50%;
    max-height: 300px;
    display: block;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent-element">
    <div class="div-one">
    </div>
    <div class="div-two">
    </div>
    <div class="div-three">
      <ul class="scrollable-list">
          <li>List Item 1</li>
          <li>List Item 2</li>
          <li>List Item 3</li>
                  <li>List Item 1</li>
          <li>List Item 2</li>
          <li>List Item 3</li>
        <li>List Item 1</li>
          <li>List Item 2</li>
          <li>List Item 3</li>
              <li>List Item 1</li>
          <li>List Item 2</li>
          <li>List Item 3</li>
            <li>List Item 1</li>
          <li>List Item 2</li>
          <li>List Item 3</li>
               <li>List Item 1</li>
          <li>List Item 2</li>
          <li>List Item 3</li>
              <li>List Item 1</li>
          <li>List Item 2</li>
          <li>List Item 3</li>
           <li>List Item 1</li>
          <li>List Item 2</li>
          <li>List Item 3</li>
           <li>List Item 1</li>
          <li>List Item 2</li>
          <li>List Item 3</li>
          <li>List Item 1</li>
          <li>List Item 2</li>
          <li>List Item 3</li>
                <li>List Item 1</li>
          <li>List Item 2</li>
          <li>List Item 3</li>
              <li>List Item 1</li>
          <li>List Item 2</li>
          <li>List Item 3</li>
                 <li>List Item 1</li>
          <li>List Item 2</li>
          <li>List Item 3</li>
                    <li>List Item 1</li>
          <li>List Item 2</li>
          <li>List Item 3</li>
      
      </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```